# How to automate work-flow of Electron app with Angular 2

Tags: angular, electron, angular-cli

I want to develop an Electron app with Angular 2.
I managed to create a "hello world" Angular 2 app with Angular CLI (1.0.0-beta.21) and it runs fine with `ng serve`.

When I run `ng build` and change the `<base href="/">` in `<base href="./">` in the index.html I can run the app as an Electron app.

The problem now is that I always have to run `ng build` in order to get an updated version of the app in the `dist` folder.
In contrast to older versions the current version of Angular CLI (1.0.0-beta.21) does not update the dist folder anymore when running `ng serve`.

How can I improve this work flow?

Can I still force Angular CLI to dump every change in the dist folder?
Or is there another way to see the changes immediately in the Electron app?

Comment: Please tell me why you down-vote this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I can think of is that you could run a `ng build --watch` along side your 'ng serve'. That will cause the dit folder to be maintained as well.